# How do I place data from http json in a new scope variable [angularJS]

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I wrote an **$http.get** function to extract data stored in a database.

I would like to use the database data in a dropdown function in AngularJS. Now this means that I have to create a new **$scope** JSON data variable and store the actual database data in it just so I can access it in my HTML page.

```
<select popover="Choose your input drug, type to filter list of drugs" data-ng-model="currentData"
    data-ng-options="name for name in ourDataName" style="width:300px;" convert-to-number >
</select>
```

`ourDataName` in `data-ng-options` is the variable I defined inside the controller as `$scope.ourDataName`, and it is supposed to have all the drug names inside it. It is possible for me to do what is written inside the get function below; however, the problem is that there are over 100 drug names:

```
$http.get(URL).success(function (data) {  //Note URL is where I stored my database. I did not put it for privacy reasons
    $scope.ourDataName = 
        [
            data[1].drug_name,
            data[2].drug_name,
            data[3].drug_name
        ]   
});
```

I tried to put a `for` loop over the JSON data as such:

```
for(var i=0; i<100;i++)
{
    $scope.ourDataName = 
    [
        data[i].drug_name
    ]   
}
```

The problem is it ended up showing the 100th drug name only since it shows what the loop ends at.

I am out of solutions. Is there any way to loop through the database and store them in a new variable without having to go over each as I did at first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create another data set for dropdown.

Use data directly which http get return.

Try like this

**Controller**

```
$http.get(URL).success(function (data) {        //Note URL is where I stored my database. I did not put it for privacy reasons
   $scope.ourDataName=data;
});
```

**View**

```
<select popover="Choose your input drug, type to filter list of drugs"  data-ng-model="currentData"
   data-ng-options="name.drug_name for name in ourDataName" style="width:300px;" convert-to-number >
</select>
```

Comment: Change `name.name` to `name.drug_name`.

Answer (score 1):

Anik's answer is great. But if you want to go with a loop option, you can use the below code in your controller.

```
$scope.ourDataName = [];
$http.get(URL).success(function (data) {    
  angular.forEach(data, function(drug) {
    $scope.ourDataName.push(drug.drug_name);
  });
});
```